# Windows 2008R2 two node failover cluster creation fails

Tags: windows, failovercluster

We have just installed two Windows 2008R2 Enterprise machines with identical hardware. When  running the cluster validation everything is ok. When creating the cluster it fails with the following error:

```
An error occurred while creating the cluster.
An error occurred creating cluster 'CLUSTER04'.
The parameter is incorrect
```

The logfile on the first node where we are running our config from, does not show any errors.

On the second node we get:

```
The Cluster service is shutting down because quorum was lost. 
This could be due to the loss of network connectivity between
some or all nodes in the cluster, or a failover of the witness disk.
```

I've double checked and all communication between the servers are fine. Even when creating a one node cluster it gives the error. There are other failover clusters we have setup without any issues.

Answer (score 2):

The fault was the number of ACL's applied to the computer object, after reducing the number of ACL's the creation of the cluster succeeded.